# "Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]" when trying to pass data from modal to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to pass an object (an array) from a modal to a controller but I am getting this error:

```
"Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]"
```

I've declared a function into resolve that returns the array and injected the function into the controller but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**Below is the modal:**

```
$scope.cercaClienteNomeCognome = function() {
    if ($scope.nome == undefined){
        var name = "";
    } else name = angular.uppercase($scope.nome);
    if ($scope.cognome == undefined){
        var surname = "";
    } else surname = angular.uppercase($scope.cognome);
    var url = "servizi/getClienteNomeCognome?nomeCliente="+name+"&cognomeCliente="+surname;
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'partials/modals/estensioneRicerca.html',
                controller: 'estensioneRicercaController',
                size : 'lg',
                backdrop: 'static',
                //keyboard: false,
                resolve: {
                    returnArrayClienti: function () {
                           return data;
                         }
                }
            });
        }

    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        toaster.pop({
            type    : "Error",
            title   : "Ouh nou!",
            body    : "[RECUPERO CLIENTI] Errore durante il ritrovamento dei clienti"
        });
    });
};
```

**And this is the controller:**

```
    angular.module("itasAcquire.controllers")
.controller('estensioneRicercaController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'ConfigPropertiesService', 'toaster', '$log', '$http', 'returnArrayClienti',
                      function ($scope, $rootScope, ConfigPropertiesService, toaster, $log, $http, returnArrayClienti) {


     $scope.mostraToasterTemporaneo = function() {
         var clienti = returnArrayClienti;
         var clienti = null;
            if (clienti == undefined) { 
                toaster.pop({
                    type    : "Success",
                    title   : "WAIT!",
                    body    : "Attenzione! Non e' stato selezionato alcun tipo documento!"

            });
            } else {
                toaster.pop({
                    type    : "Success",
                    title   : "Congrats!",
                    body    : "Il cliente è stato selezionato!  (" + clienti.CODICE_FISCALE + ")"
                });
            }
     };


}]);
```

**EDIT: following a screenshot of the error:**
[image]

Comment: which modal service are you using? AngularStrap? a custom one? And is it definitely your resolve that can't be injected? you haven't put the full error.

Comment: I think that you are missing the $modal injection to your controller.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas I don't need it. I'm not using a modal into the controller ;)

Comment: @M21B8 AngularStrap. The full error is in the screenshot... it seems like I have to use a service to pass data between this modal (positioned into a controller) and the modal's controller...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution by myself: I'm pretty sure the problem was about a conflict between controllers (since the modal was in ctrl1 and I was passing data from modal to ctrl2) so all I had to do was add a service that wraps all the modal's logic...